# Question Review - Does this type of question actually belong to Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, review-queues, review-audits, scope

Please have a look at

https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/14424858

or,

[What goes in a Stack package.yaml file?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40332040/1151929)

It appeared "as a test" when I was reviewing the close requests on questions,

As per my understanding the question just asks, if a *specification* exists for `package.yaml` for cabal packages.

As per what I have understood about Stack Overflow... this question does not about programming as per most of the guidelines.

I have seen questions which were far more detailed and specific to programming being flagged and closed as off-topic by people.

But sometimes, when questions like this are asked by people with decent reputation, not only will these be answered by community they will even receive up-votes.

Though, I understand the fact that the seriousness and relevance of a question is subjective to the view-point of community and can not be so objectively explained.

But... when you see such question appear "as a test" while reviewing, its just unreasonable because such questions should be considered off-topic from an objective view point and considering the guidelines on Stack Overflow.

I think that the questions under review should be limited to the communities/technologies that the *user* knows about (Or tags that the *user* has subscribed to) so that he can actually understand the question subjectively instead of just objectively thinking in terms of Stack Overflow guidelines.

Comment: Questions about a standard build tool for a language are certainly on topic on a programmer's site.  The Q+A having 14 helpful votes is a fair ringing endorsement that it is considered useful by [haskell] programmers.  And makes it rather simple to pass an audit.  But you have to pay attention, the kind of thing an audit checks for.

Comment: @HansPassant Correct me if I am wrong, but I think the "test" questions do not show the actual votes and other interactions on the question. Also... is this question not similar to asking `Is there a link where I can find ES6 features supported by node.js ?`. This is as easy as a google seach for node.js but such things may not be so easy to find for some other tool etc. And this is why I think that the reviewers knowledge about the technology/tool is important.

Answer (score 1):

From the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic):

> if your question generally covers
>
> ...
>
> - software tools commonly used by programmers; and is
> - a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development
>
> then you’re in the right place to ask your question!

According to the [tag excerpt](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/haskell-stack/info):

> stack is a modern, cross-platform build tool for Haskell code.

So the question is on-topic.

---

> I think that the questions under review should be limited to the communities/technologies that the user knows about (Or tags that the user has subscribed to) so that he can actually understand the question subjectively instead of just objectively thinking in terms of stackoverflow guidelines.

That's very easy; you can use tags to filter most review queues (Triage is the only exception). This has another advantage for you: that audits are easier to spot, because those aren't filtered. You can still get this question as an audit if you filter on [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java).

Comment: It's off-topic for asking for an off-site resource though: *Does a specification exist?*...